# Passing a pointer by reference to class and using it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pointers

I am trying to pass a pointer by reference to an object from class A to class B. In class B I want to assign this pointer to a ivar and read and write to it.

This is the code that gives me errors (does not matter what errors). This is my first try with pointers so please correct my understanding.

```
Class A

//This is the parameter I would like to pass as a pointer and be able to manipulate from class B
NSString *name = @"Cyprian";

-(void)passAParameter{

   ClassB *classB = [[ClassB alloc] initWithAPointer:&name];
   ...
}


Class B

// ClassB.h
@interface ClassB{

    NSString **nameFromClassA;
}
@property(nonatomic,assign)NSString **nameFromClassA;

-(id)initWithAPointer:(NSString **)name;
// ClassB.m


@implementation ClassB

@synthesize nameFromClassA;

-(id)initWithAPointer:(NSString **)name{
   *nameFromClassA = *name;
}

//Print the name
-(void)printName{
   NSLog(@"Name: %@", *nameFromClassA);
}

//Will this change the name in class A?
-(void)changeNameInClassA:(NSString* newName){
   *nameFromClassA = newName;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, do not use double pointers here. You shouldn't handle things like that.
This is a simpler approach:

In the `ClassA` instance:

```
-(void)passAParameter{
   NSString *name = @"Cyprian";
   ClassB *classB = [[ClassB alloc] initWithAPointer:name];
   ...
}
```

While you define `ClassB` this way:
ClassB.h:

```
@interface ClassB{    

    NSString *nameFromClassA;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *nameFromClassA; // Retaining it will give you less headaches

-(id)initWithAPointer:(NSString *)name;
@end
```

ClassB.m:

```
@implementation ClassB

@synthesize nameFromClassA;

// You should release all retained object when deallocating self
- (void) dealloc {
    [nameFromClassA release];
    nameFromClassA = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

-(id)initWithAPointer:(NSString *)name{
    if ((self = [super init])) {     // Always init the object from super!
        self.nameFromClassA = name;  // Retain the object calling self.
    }
    return self;
}

//Print the name
-(void)printName{
   NSLog(@"Name: %@", nameFromClassA);
}

//Will this change the name in class A?
-(void)changeNameInClassA:(NSString* newName){
    self.nameFromClassA = newName; // Retain it calling self.
}

@end
```

Comment: Well I guess I didn't make my self clear enough. I want to pass a value by reference so i use double pointers on purpose. I am trying to pass a name by reference so I can read from it and write to it in class B.

Comment: If you pass it the way I exposed here, each change on `name` in `ClassA` will "pass" to `nameFromClassA` in `ClassB`, since you are naturally using a pointer to refer to that string. You are initializing `ClassB` using the pointer to the memory that "contains" the string (in fact you define the string as `NSString *name` and not `NSString name`).

Comment: Please, try it and let me know if you have difficulties.

Comment: you are right, I don't know why this idea came to my mind. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The assignment in your `initWithAPointer:` method should be just:

```
nameFromClassA = name;
```

That said, this code pattern smells of a bad design.  What high-level goal is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ok I am trying to open an universal editor that will edit a table cells title, so I would like to pass table cell by reference and read and write to it from my editor

Comment: Then you should pass the table cell (using a normal object pointer like `(UITableViewCell *)`) and update the title property of the cell.  Or, probably better yet, you should design a delegate protocol whereby your universal editor notifies the view controller that contains the cell when the title changes.